# Template Parse error: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined (" in angular 2 when trying to use pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to add some search parameters that allow the user to filter what they see but everytime I add the pipe, it gives me an error.

Here is my template. It's specifically adding in the filter in the ngFor loop that causes the error.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <h2>Product Catalogue</h2>
  <input [(ngModel)]="productFilter.productname" placeholder="search">

  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event" id="1"
                      maxSize="5"
                      directionLinks="true"
                      autoHide="true">
                </pagination-controls>
  <table class="col-sm-12">
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name </th>
      <th>Vintage </th>
      <th>Volume</th>
      <th>Product Number </th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ">
      <td><a [routerLink] = "['/', id, product.prodid]">  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td> {{product.vintage}}</td>
      <td> {{product.volume}}</td>
      <td> {{product.lcbo}}</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Here is my pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class ProductpipePipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(items: Array<any>, filter: {[key: string]: any }): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => {
                let notMatchingField = Object.keys(filter)
                                             .find(key => item[key] !== filter[key]);

                return !notMatchingField; // true if matches all fields
            });
  }

}
```

edit:
Here is the productFilter object

```
productFilter = {productname: "",
};
```

Here is the entire error message:

```
 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
    </tr>

    <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("Filter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ">
      <td><a [ERROR ->][routerLink] = "['/', id, product.prodid]">  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td> {{product."): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@30:13
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("uctFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ">
      <td>[ERROR ->]<a [routerLink] = "['/', id, product.prodid]">  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td> {{produ"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@30:10, Directive RouterLinkWithHref
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("uctFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ">
      <td>[ERROR ->]<a [routerLink] = "['/', id, product.prodid]">  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td> {{produ"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@30:10, Directive RouterLinkWithHref
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("uctFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ">
      <td>[ERROR ->]<a [routerLink] = "['/', id, product.prodid]">  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td> {{produ"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@30:10, Directive RouterLinkWithHref
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("rrentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ">
      <td><a [routerLink] = "['/', id, product.prodid]">[ERROR ->]  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td> {{product.vintage}}</td>
      <td> {{product.volume}"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@30:56
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("   <td><a [routerLink] = "['/', id, product.prodid]">  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td>[ERROR ->] {{product.vintage}}</td>
      <td> {{product.volume}}</td>
      <td> {{product.lcbo}}</td>
"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@31:10
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("product.prodid]">  {{product.productname}} </a> </td>
      <td> {{product.vintage}}</td>
      <td>[ERROR ->] {{product.volume}}</td>
      <td> {{product.lcbo}}</td>
    </tr>
"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@32:10
Parser Error: Unexpected token |, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: {itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index  ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@29:8 ("
      <td> {{product.vintage}}</td>
      <td> {{product.volume}}</td>
      <td>[ERROR ->] {{product.lcbo}}</td>
    </tr>

"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@33:10
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22761:34)
    at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33882:19)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48034:39)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47954:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47954:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47841:19
    at Object.then (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:22750:148)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47840:26)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47769:37)
syntaxError @ compiler.es5.js:1690
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse @ compiler.es5.js:12811
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate @ compiler.es5.js:26963
(anonymous) @ compiler.es5.js:26883
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents @ compiler.es5.js:26883
(anonymous) @ compiler.es5.js:26770
then @ compiler.es5.js:1679
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.es5.js:26769
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.es5.js:26698
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ core.es5.js:4535
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ core.es5.js:4521
../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 31d40e39a28f00c92d63:54
2 @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 31d40e39a28f00c92d63:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 31d40e39a28f00c92d63:25
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

Comment: None of what you've posted uses `toUpperCase`. Perhaps you should look in `productFilter`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it gives me this error nonetheless. The product filter is just a json object. I'll put it up, but I don't think its causing the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `None of what you've posted uses toUpperCase. Perhaps you should look in productFilter` The error is coming from angular compiler. It is trying to construct structural directive like ngFor + `of`.toUpperCase

Comment: @yurzui ah, well that might be clearer with the actual traceback!

Comment: I will post te entire error message as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `;`

```
*ngFor="let product of products | filter: productFilter;  |  paginate: ...
                                                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the rendering error. Now I just need to fix the issue I seem to be having with the pipe.....

Comment: how would this work in combination with "index"?
like: *ngFor="let item of _items; let i = index  | callback: filterItem"

Answer (score 1):

As answered above you should remove `;`
and if you want to use filter with index you can use:

`*ngFor="let product of products | filter: productFilter; let i= index`

`index` should be after `filter` and `;` should be used in `filter`